# Align view on the border of different backgrounds in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I should achieve such effect in `ConstraintLayout` as below
[image]

I know how to create the custom `ProgressBar`, but I have no idea 
how to align this `view` on the border of different backgrounds
Please, provide a hint.

Comment: Please be more specific. What is a problem? What do you mean by alligning view on the boarder od different backgrounds? And please post some code

Comment: @muminers The solution is already posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to acomplish this using horizontal guidelines.
One can be set X dp before the end of the top view and another one X dp after the begining of the second view.
And finally the progress could be vertically constrined in the middle betwee the two guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. By the way, I have implemented this and provided code below.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on idea of this answer( [answer of Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235103/align-view-on-the-border-of-different-backgrounds-in-constraintlayout/49235227#49235227) )

Result is:
[image]

Code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/col_yellow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/g_top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/g_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".4"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/g_top_above"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/g_top_below"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".45"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_completion"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background_layer_list"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/g_top_below"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/g_top_above"
        tools:progress="100"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```